# Tensorflow variable scope: reuse if variable exists

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want a piece of code that creates a variable within a scope if it doesn't exist, and access the variable if it already exists. I need it to be the **same** code since it will be called multiple times.

However, Tensorflow needs me to specify whether I want to create or reuse the variable, like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"): #create the first time
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])

with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True): #reuse the second time
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
```

How can I get it to figure out whether to create or reuse it automatically? I.e., I want the above two blocks of code to be the **same** and have the program run.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `ValueError` is raised in `get_variable()` when creating a new variable and shape is not declared, or when violating reuse during variable creation. Therefore, you can try this:

```
def get_scope_variable(scope_name, var, shape=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name) as scope:
        try:
            v = tf.get_variable(var, shape)
        except ValueError:
            scope.reuse_variables()
            v = tf.get_variable(var)
    return v

v1 = get_scope_variable('foo', 'v', [1])
v2 = get_scope_variable('foo', 'v')
assert v1 == v2
```

Note that the following also works:

```
v1 = get_scope_variable('foo', 'v', [1])
v2 = get_scope_variable('foo', 'v', [1])
assert v1 == v2
```

---

**UPDATE.** The new API supports auto-reusing now:

```
def get_scope_variable(scope, var, shape=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        v = tf.get_variable(var, shape)
    return v
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with top-level scope (i.e., no scope)?

Comment: @holdenlee Yes, just set the scope to `''` (i.e. an empty string)

Comment: [`tf.make_template`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/make_template) is also useful for creating new variables if they dont exist and silently reusing ones if they do.

Answer (score 13):

Although using "try...except..." clause works, I think a more elegant and maintainable way would be separate the variable initialization process with the "reuse" process.

```
def initialize_variable(scope_name, var_name, shape):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name) as scope:
        v = tf.get_variable(var_name, shape)
        scope.reuse_variable()

def get_scope_variable(scope_name, var_name):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse=True):
        v = tf.get_variable(var_name)
    return v
```

Since often we only need to initialize variable ones, but reuse/share it for many times, separating the two processes make the code cleaner. Also this way, we won't need to go through the "try" clause every time to check if the variable has been created already or not.

Answer (score 13):

New AUTO_REUSE option does the trick.

From the [tf.variable_scope API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope): if `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE`, we create variables if they do not exist, and return them otherwise.

Basic example of sharing a variable AUTO_REUSE:

```
def foo():
  with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
  return v

v1 = foo()  # Creates v.
v2 = foo()  # Gets the same, existing v.
assert v1 == v2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write our abstraction over `tf.varaible_scope` than uses `reuse=None` on the first call and uses `reuse=True` on the consequent calls:

```
def variable_scope(name_or_scope, *args, **kwargs):
  if isinstance(name_or_scope, str):
    scope_name = tf.get_variable_scope().name + '/' + name_or_scope
  elif isinstance(name_or_scope, tf.Variable):
    scope_name = name_or_scope.name

  if scope_name in variable_scope.scopes:
    kwargs['reuse'] = True
  else:
    variable_scope.scopes.add(scope_name)

  return tf.variable_scope(name_or_scope, *args, **kwargs)
variable_scope.scopes = set()
```

Usage:

```
with variable_scope("foo"): #create the first time
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])

with variable_scope("foo"): #reuse the second time
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
```