# TensorFlow: Is there a way to initialize variables in variable scope if they're not initialized, and reuse them if they are?

Tags: python, coding-style, tensorflow

I'm trying to write "clean" code. What I want to do is

```
if(var exists)
    var = tf.get_variable(...)
else
    var = init_var
```

I tried doing this with a try-except, like so:

```
try:
   with scope('my scope'):
       var = tf.get_variable('v', reuse=True)
except ValueError:
   with scope('my scope'):
       var = tf.get_variable('v', reuse=False)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
I've tried looking for examples online, but haven't found anything close to the case I'm trying to solve, which is to cleanly use a large network where almost every variable is under a different scope.

Comment: I don't know about TensorFlow part, but I think the exception should be `NameError` (instead of `ValueError`) if you want to check whether a variable exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

tf.get_variable() has no reuse parameter.

The question is already answered here:
[Tensorflow variable scope: reuse if variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545362/tensorflow-variable-scope-reuse-if-variable-exists)