# What's the usage of variable_scope with name_or_scope = None

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, gpu

When we use variable_scope, we usually set the first argument (`name_or_scope`) as a name of variable_scope. And when we set the reuse variable as 'True', we can share the variable within the variable_scope.
However, I found that inside the tensorflow API (such as Bahdanau attention, or `tf.layers.Dense`), there are variable scope whose first argument (`name_or_scope`) is set as `None` and the second argument (`default_name`) is set as what we thought as scope name. 
I checked the code of `tf.variable_scope` and found that:

> If `name_or_scope` is not None, it is used as is. If `scope` is None,
>   then   `default_name` is used.  In that case, if the same name has
>   been previously   used in the same scope, it will be made unique by
>   appending `_N` to it.

In this case, I can't use it within for loop because each time the variable_scope is called, it will create new `variable_scope` with different name.

I can't find anywhere explaining this function (I mean `name_or_scope` set as `None`).

Anyone to explain this?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545362/tensorflow-variable-scope-reuse-if-variable-exists?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ManojJadhav My question was that : How variable_scope work when name_or_scope = None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, when `tf.variable_scope` is called with `name_or_scope=None`, a `default_name` argument is used and it's uniquified. So calling it in a loop will create different scopes.

Not sure about *Bahdanau attention*, but `tf.layers.Dense` can be created with a custom scope via `_scope` argument:

```
layer = Dense(units, ..., _scope=name)
```

In fact, you can call [`tf.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) with a specified `name` and this name is going to define `tf.variable_scope(name)`. This way allows you to create dense layers in a loop.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot.Thanks. However, Can you explain little bit more about why they created such a function? I mean, in what situation that the argument with None value 'name_or_scope = None' should be used.

Comment: One use-case is to forbid variable reuse, in other words force unique scope. Also you may want to avoid nested scope name to make it look nicer in tensorboard. Here's an example in tf source base: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py#L192