# Reusing a tensorflow model inside a for loop from another module

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run a tf program from within another module. The tf program applies [deep deblurring](https://github.com/jiangsutx/SRN-Deblur) to images and works fine if I apply it to a single folder from console using the arguments provided in the repository (I am using python3 instead but it does not seem to be a problem with that):

```
python3 run_model.py --input_path=./testing_set --output_path=./testing_res --height=720 --width=1280 --gpu=0
```

The problem is that when I try to run the deblur module multiple time it complains saying:

> ValueError: Variable g_net/enc1_1/weights already exists, disallowed.
>   Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

The line that causes trouble is this [one](https://github.com/jiangsutx/SRN-Deblur/blob/master/models/model.py#L271):

```
outputs = self.generator(inputs, reuse=False)
```

The module is run flawlessly for the first folder though and complains about the next one.

Since I basically apply inference to a every folder I have separately (that's the intention at least) I guessed I could try `reuse=True`. But this seem to cause another issue:

> ValueError: Variable g_net/enc1_1/weights does not exist, or was not
>   created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

It does not seem to find this variable any more if I set it to reuse. This seems peculiar enough.

Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38895052/3584765) it seems that when set to `reuse` tf assumes the variable already exists, and so when not found it complains.

I couldn't find out the actual variable that I should check for existence (maybe all inside the model?) so I applied a `try...except` clause to the whole [`with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=False):`](https://github.com/jiangsutx/SRN-Deblur/blob/master/models/model.py#L74) clause. This seems to work for multiple folders but it complains in 5th folder:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 46 and 45 for
>   'g_net_6/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [1,46,80,64],
>   [1,45,80,64].

The folder contains images of different input size so that's the reason it complains I guess.

As a final attempt I even tried to create a new deblur model for each folder (inside a for loop for example) by calling the model constructor every time:

```
deblur = model.DEBLUR(args)
...
deblur.test(h, w, input_path, output_path)
```

This does not seem to work either for some reason. I am certainly missing something here.

A new session is declared inside the `deblur.test()` so this should work as far as I get it.

So, a few questions have risen:

1. Although the `try..except` clause seems to work I couldn't figure out which variable is being affected or (if as I suspect multiple variables are affected) where does this happen. I see model weight being initialized inside `slim.arg_scope()`. Does this mean `reuse` argument is passed here and treats the variables differently?
2. Why the re-initialization of model inside my script does not work as expected? Tensorflow seems to remember the variables and to use the same session over and over for some reason. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? I tried defining `deblur = None` at the end of my loop or using `with tf.Session...` inside `deblur.test()` but nothing seems to change this behavior.
3. My fist choice (and more efficient one I guess) to reuse the tf model and not reinitialize it if needed but I am not sure if this possible in my case and if so how can I do it.

Comment: As the `test` method is written, I suppose the only way to use it multiple times in a loop would be to wrap it in a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` context, since it recreates and loads the checkpoint for the model every time. This is a significant overhead, and also the method creates a `tf.Session` that is not closed.

Comment: Do you suggest to add `with tf.Graph().as_default():`inside the `test` function? As for the session I already mentioned I replaced it with a `with tf.Session` so I guess it's no closed.

Comment: Adding that to the function would probably be a better option I think, yes.

Comment: @jdehesa I tried it and when a folder with different image size occur it still throws an error about Dimensions misfit. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure what that may be about, sounds like it may be a different issue but can't really tell.