# tf.train.Saver not loading in same process

Tags: tensorflow

I am observing a strange behavior where Saver can't restore if the checkpoint was saved earlier in the same Python process. It loads fine if done from a different process. Here's some simple code that will show the problem.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

def train():
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")

def predict():
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")

train()
predict()
```

Here we save and restore immediately after that in the same process. Restoration fails with errors like:

```
Key Variable_1 not found in checkpoint
```

But if I run just the predict() code again from a new Python process it works just fine.

```
#train()
predict()
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `predict`, if you run:

```
print([v for v in tf.trainable_variables()])
```

you will see that two different variables are being created. That's why TF is not able to restore the value of the second one.

---

In order to link both variables into a single one, you can either:

- Pass a dictionary to the argument `var_list` of [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver). For example:

  ```
  saver = tf.train.Saver({'W': W})
  ```
- Use [auto-reusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545362/tensorflow-variable-scope-reuse-if-variable-exists/38895052#38895052) when creating the [variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables). For example:

  ```
  with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
      W = tf.get_variable(initializer=lambda: tf.zeros([1, 1]),
                          name='W')
  ```